# Как выбрать продукты, которые клиенты наиболее склонны купить?

Tags: python

У компании есть несколько продуктов, которые она продает на b2c рынке. Продукты А, В и С.

Для каждого продукта была построена отдельная модель, которая показывает вероятность покупки клиентами данного продукта. Каждая модель предсказывает факт покупки (0 или 1) и вероятность. Например, клиент купит продукт А с вероятностью 65%.

Модели на каждый продукт были запущены, и результаты были записаны в таблицу. Хотим предложить клиентам купить продукты, которые они наиболее склонны купить (на основе результатов моделей).

Но получилась следующая ситуация: Клиент 1 готов купить продукт А с вероятностью 65%, продукт В с вероятностью 60% и продукт С с вероятностью 55%. Клиент 2 не готов купить ни один из продуктов, но вероятность покупки продукта А - 30%, продукта В - 20%, а продукта С - 10%.

Получается, что для каждого клиента вероятность покупки продукта А всегда выше, чем вероятность покупки продуктов В и С. Но продукт А является специфическим (для узкого сегмента клиентов). И его нецелесообразно предлагать всем клиентам.

Вопрос: можно ли посчитать реальную вероятность покупки продуктов, чтобы клиентам предлагался не только продукт А, но и продукты В и С?

При моделировании использовались разные обучающие выборки (по количеству наблюдений). У продукта А была маленькая обучающая выборка, т.к. количество целевых событий мало, а у продуктов В и С были большие обучающие выборки, т.к. целевых событий было много.

Comment: А не получилось ли у вас ошибки при подсчете? Из серии "сначала 50% покупают С, потом 50% покупают В, а потом 50% покупают А" - при такой последовательности у А - 50%, у В - 25%, а у С - 12,5%.

Comment: Вопрос неясен. Если вы построили модели которые вам выдают такие проценты - отлаживайте модели, а не подгоняйте результаты под "нам кажется должно быть нормализовано".

Comment: Ошибки быть не должно. Т.к. для каждого продукта строилась отдельная модель. И модели не были связаны друг с другом.

Comment: Попробуйте переформулировать вопрос. Сейчас он звучит как *"Мы построили модель и она говорит что черных ворон 99%, а белых 1%. Можно ли нормализовать вероятность рождения белых ворон, чтобы их стало 50%?"*

Comment: Я предполагаю, что вероятности, которые получаются на выходе, можно нормализовать, т.к. обучающие выборки были разного объема (зависели от количества целевых событий на обучении).
Т.е. хочу нормализовать вероятности с учетом размера обучающей выборки.

Comment: При чем тут размер выборки? Если из 100 человек, 80 купили А, а из 50 - 15 купили С, то как вы собираетесь подтасовывать результат, чтобы из 1000, 800 купили А и 700 купили С ? Какие у вас основания полагать, что ваша выборка нерепрезентативна, и что вы ее будете "руками исправлять".

Comment: На текущий момент получается следующая ситуация. Есть 1000 клиентов. 900 клиентам предлагается продукт A, 50 клиентам предлагается продукт B и 50 клиентам предлагается продукт C. При этом продукт А являются специфическим, т.е. для узкого сегмента клиентов. При нормализации вероятностей хочу получить примерно следующее: продукт А предлагается 300 клиентам, продукт В предлагается 500 клиентам и продукт С предлагается 200 клиентам. Возможно ли это сделать? Или необходимо перестраивать модели?

Comment: Попробуйте переформулировать вопрос с самого начала. Опишите что у вас есть и чего вы хотите добиться. Какова изначальная проблема?

Comment: В текущей формулировке вопрос не очень понятен. Вы строили отдельную модель для каждого продукта? PS было бы уместным выложить ваш код на какой-нибудь GitHub и указать ссылку, чтобы было понятно как вы строили модели. Кроме того не помешал бы набор данных (клиентов лучше предварительно анонимизировать) - тогда можно было бы построить модель и посмотреть что там к чему...

Comment: Попробую переформулировать вопрос. У компании есть 3 продукта. Для каждого продукта была построена отдельная модель. Каждая модель предсказывает вероятность покупки клиентом данного продукта. Мы примени 3 модели и записали результаты в таблицу. Получилось следующее: модели предсказывают, что клиент готов купить все 3 продукта, но вероятность покупки продукта А выше, чем вероятность покупки продуктов В и С. А другой клиент не готов купить ни один из продуктов (вероятности менее 50%), но вероятность покупки продукта А (40%) выше, чем вероятность покупки продуктов В (30%) и С (20%).

Comment: Мы хотим отправлять клиентам предложение о покупке того продукта, у которого наибольшая вероятность. А получается, что всем клиентам отправим предложение купить продукт А, потому что у него наибольшая вероятность для каждого клиента, чем у продуктов В и С. При этом продукт А является специфическим (для узкого сегмента клиентов), и он точно не будет востребован всеми клиентами. В связи с этим возникает вопрос: можно ли скорректировать вероятности покупки продуктов, чтобы кому-то отправить предложение о покупке продуктов В и С?

Comment: Есть предположение, что нормализовать вероятности можно с помощью обучающей выборки. Продукт А специфический, для моделирования была использована небольшая выборка, т.к. мало целевых действий. А для продуктов В и С были использованы большие обучающие выборки, т.к. количество целевых событий для обучения велико.

Comment: @AleksandrGump перенесите ваши комментарии в вопрос, (кнопка править)

Comment: @Kromster, я актуализировал вопрос. Буду признателен, если сможете помочь в его решении.

Comment: Видится противоречие в вопросе. С одной стороны вероятность покупки А выше всех, а с другой стороны вы утверждаете что он нишевый и никому не нужен? Как так?

Comment: Для нас это тоже загадка.
Есть 2 предположения:
1. Нужно вычислить реальную вероятность на основе вероятности, которую получаем в модели. Для вычисления реальной вероятности можно использовать отношение обучающей выборки ко всей выборке и/или учитывать максимальные и минимальные вероятности для каждого продукта. Здесь нужна помощь в составлении формулы. Возможно, кто-то с этим сталкивался.
2. Перестроить модель.